# Is there a way to toggle VPN in iOS shortcuts?

Tags: ios, vpn, shortcuts-app

Is there a way to toggle VPN trough shortcuts in iOS 12?

Looked into it, but can't really find anything.

Comment: As this seems impossible for now, I have posted a feature request to Apple.

Comment: Some VPN apps (TunnelBear and the Passepartout beta are the only ones I’ve used) have Siri shortcuts that you can control in the Shortcuts app for turning it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a VPN app installed. When you connect to the VPN for the first time (via this installed app OR configuration URL), iOS enables a hidden tag in settings named VPN. This tile isn’t enabled by default, so check if you were connected before to any service or not. This setting was just created to manage an existing connection.
and my second solution is this url : prefs:root=General&path=VPN . but to use this url you need to connect existing app or shortcut (going there with safari does nothing and url is very unstable). [here is download of my version of shortcut](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HtftX3M_BbKxTyQ6QGfe7_ssYyl1oivv/view?usp=drivesdk) and sorry for google drive but i'm logged out of icloud :/ . and here is printscreen of code (i'm doing that due to security reasons and people just don't trust me so...) here it is: [image]

Comment: The question is about using a Shortcut to enable/disable VPNs, not about Settings.

Comment: yes but without external app you can't normally unlock this part of settings

Comment: anyways - comment updated :)

Comment: Or quite simply: open url prefs:root=VPN